# How can I see events from multiple calendars not owned by me in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2007, calendar

In Outlook 2007, I have access to my calendar and two other calendars.

Is it possible to see the other two users' calendars overlaid on each other while not seeing events from my own calendar? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the 3 check boxes next to the two calendars you want to overlay plus your own calendar so that they are all checked.

Once that is done uncheck your own calendar so now only the calendars you want to overlay are checked. Then you can see the two calendars side by side in the view and click the little arrow in the title of one of the calendars to overlay both of them.

Comment: Thanks, the arrow on my own calendar only appeared when there is a calendar overlaid onto it. So your logic of stacking them all and pulling mine off, worked. Thanks

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple calendars open there should be an arrow in the title of the calendar that you can click on and push that calendar into overlay mode

Check out the link below

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-calendars-side-by-side-or-overlaid-HA001230157.aspx

Comment: I was looking for all other calendars to be overlaid on eachother, and keep mine separate. The other answer solves this. Thanks.

Comment: glad you got it figured out, I missed the part where you wanted to keep your calendar separate